# May Noahidism be a religion

Tags: noahidism

Is Noahidism a religion?  Can it be practiced as a religion?  At least a couple of the commandments in my opinion are not immediately evident (evar min hachai, blessing the name, appropriate relationships, etc.) but over time.  A person in their natural state, having no prior knowledge or conviction of these, may not act on them.

At least e''h is specific dietary and is bound to be a religious fulfillment, I think.

Would a person be able to identify as a Noahide on a religious questionnaire? Several major publications on the matter indicate that it is an ideology and that leaves doubt if a person is given to this, or derived from some other religion, rather than an end to itself, is supplementary.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is off topic. It's not about Judaism, since Judaism doesn't have a category of "religion" or "religious questionnaire"

Comment: No. Noahides are gentiles with Jewish beliefs. It is not a separate religion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Judaism.

Comment: This is an interesting question which may fit into a different SE site - not sure which one. If I remember, I'll post  a comment from the "official" Noahide web site. I'm pretty sure someone asked this same question, there. You're not the only one with this concern. (I'm uncertain why in the U.S. questionnaires ask about your religion. When is that info really relevant?)

Comment: "At least e''h is specific dietary and is bound to be a religious fulfillment" - technically, no. Noahide commandments are binding to all of humanity. Generally, what identifies a religion is a set of unique rules that are different. In fact, those that do perform a"h, and certainly the many people in the world that are murderers and terrorists are not following the rules incumbent on all humanity. Not to discount the concept of Noahidism at all. But, if humanity followed the rules, there wouldn't be a need for a Noahide group.

Comment: This seems to be about Judaism and thus not off-topic (because Noahidism is adherence to the principles *that Judaism requires* without being Jewish), but I recommend closure as "unclear" (or "opinion-based") because you haven't defined "religion" or "religious" and those words have no standard definition in Judaism (or in general afaik).

Comment: @msh210 Fair enough.  I see what you mean about the definition of religion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fascinating question as it touched upon a very interesting Rambam in Hilchos Melachim (10:9). The Rambam couples together with the law that a gentile is not permitted to study Torah or keep shabbos, even if he kept it during the week (as a regular shabbos) he is culpable. Furthermore he is not allowed to make his own festival. Says the Rambam, a general rule: **A Noahide is not permitted to create his own religion for himself, and to perform commandments from his own ideas. Either he should convert and become a full fledged Jew or he should remain with the 7 laws given to him, and he cannot add or subtract from them**.

The question here is, if the Ben Noach were to "create a religion" from the 7 laws would that be problematic? Or because he is neither adding or subtracting from the 7 laws it is not "creating" a religion.

I believe that the simple reading of the Rambam indicates that because the Noahide is not "creating" a new religion, but is merely identifying with the 7 Laws it would be permitted to call it a religion.

It is important to point out that earlier in the Rambam (8:12) he rules that while a gentile who accepts the 7 laws will receive a share in the world to come, this is only if the gentile accepts it as a decree from G-d, and that these are the laws that were commanded by Him through Moshe, and that the children of Noach were commanded to keep these laws. However if the gentile keeps them because they are logical, then the Gentile is not classified as a Noahide and he does not get a reward for his deeds, or is classified as a righteous gentile nor considered among their wise men.

Answer (score 0):

Someone can be an incidental Noahide: A basic  non religious person who doesn't devour living animals.
That isn't a religion but the Noahides they have today in America who lead the movement, that religion is the same as Judaism, but from the point of view of someone who isn't Jewish. They believe in all the tenets of Judaism.

Some Noahides sprinkle s bit of Christianity into their beliefs, though.

Comment: Regarding if someone can be an incidental Noahide, see my answer below quoting the Rambam that is explicitly against that assertion.